# How get actor physical path from akka actor?

Tags: scala, path, akka, actor

Here is the actor code:

```
import akka.actor.Actor

class OneActor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        //what I should call here to get ?
        case _  => println(physicalPaht)
    }
}
```

I can use some "build-in" variables:

- *context* - but it do not contains any usefull method about path
- *actorPath* - contains only local path

Any ideas?

**Updated**

Also thre is a `self.path.address` but it returns only path to root actor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`akka.serialization.Serialization.serializedActorPath(self)` should be used.

```
import akka.actor.Actor

class OneActor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case _  => println(akka.serialization.Serialization.serializedActorPath(self))
    }
}
```